# Why would my program only run if using DLL's in one specific location?

Tags: dll, dependencies, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've written a Windows program using the C API of [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) to create a nice GUI. I've installed [ActiveState ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl) for the dependencies and everything compiles and runs fine. Compiling required me to link against the import libraries provided by ActiveTcl.

Now that i want to distribute this program i have to make a choice on how to handle the dependency on ActiveTcl. One option is to require ActiveTcl be installed before my program, while another is to just distribute the ActiveTcl DLL's that my program actually uses.

If i view my program using a [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) i can see that three ActiveTcl DLL's are used. `tcl86.dll`, `tk86.dll` and `zlib1.dll`. So then i tried to move the DLL's.

If i moved these DLL's to the `C:\Windows` folder or to the program's folder, the program no longer functions. After moving the DLL's and viewing the program in the dependency walker, i can see the DLL's are being found in these alternative locations but the program refuses to start. I don't even get an error.

Do any of you guys know why this might be the case? That the only time my program runs is if the DLL's are located in the installation directory of ActiveTcl (`C:\Tcl\bin`).

Comment: Use the base dll to compile it.

Comment: The basedll should do the job.

Comment: What do you mean by use the base dll to compile? I really have no idea what that means.

Comment: What Dependency Walker says about the 3 Dlls? They may have dependencies.

Comment: @manuell There are only system dependencies in the 3 DLL's.

Comment: The you'll have to start to explain what "the program no longer functions" means.

Comment: @manuell I did, please read it again. The program doesn't start with no error message.

Comment: Start it from a debugger

Comment: Starting it from a debugger does reveal another dependency which is not in the original tcl/tk source. I'm assuming ActiveState have added their own code to avoid distribution of the dlls. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DDL's had dependencies of other files that should exist in the same folder.